# Design choices for numpy, python

Tags: python, numpy

Why does implementors of numpy in python decided to have shape for np.random.randn as comma separated ints but for np.zeros as tuple of shape?
Please explain this design choice.
Thanks

Comment: Ask the developers of numpy.

Comment: This question is totally out of the scope of SO.

Comment: This has been asked before.  Functions can be written with `args` or `args*`.  Different developers can make different choices at different times.  Consistency is nice but rarely absolution in code with a long history.

Comment: To add to your confusion, `np.reshape` takes a shape tuple, `x.shape` (method) takes either the tuple or the expanded equivalent.  Indexing takes `[1,2]` or `[(1,2)]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NumPy contains a few convenience functions [for users with a background from
Matlab](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/user/numpy-for-matlab-users.html#facilities-for-matrix-users). So NumPy named the functions the same as their Matlab equivalent, with a
[similar function call signature](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/randn.html).

Per [the docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.randn.html),

> [randn] is a convenience function.  If you want an interface that takes a
>   tuple as the first argument, use `numpy.random.standard_normal` instead.

[`numpy.random.standard_normal`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.standard_normal.html) is [equivalent](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/random/mtrand/mtrand.pyx#L1417) to [`numpy.random.randn`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.randn.html) but uses the
more native NumPy interface (with the `size` parameter).